# $\int_{S_r} \frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2} dz$ as $r\rightarrow 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

In my attempt to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}dx$ I arrived at the following expression:

$$\int_r^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}dx=\int_{S_r}\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2}dz$$

whhere $S_r=re^{it}$, $t\in[0,\pi]$. I want to calculate the right-hand integral as $r\rightarrow 0$. However, I'm stuck. I tried to use the residues theorem, beacause I know that $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2}$ has residue $i$ at $z=0$, but to use that I need to consider the other semi-circle, or another homotopic contour, to have a closed path, and it didn't help yet. I tried to use a entire function $g(z)$ such that $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z}$ and tried to expand $f$'s Laurent series, but couldn't calculate the integral yet.

If anyone could share any idea, I would be greateful

Comment: Better use the symmetry of the integral.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x -1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}$$

Comment: I tried to use some $z\rightarrow \bar{z}$ symmetry, but I couldn't get anything out of it. Could you elaborate? Also, I need to use complex analysis to solve this integral, in this case

Comment: You may try the integral of your function along the closed curve consisting of two semicircles with radius r and R, and two intervals on real line.

Comment: @jlidm that's what I did, and I arrived at the expression above. Now my difficulty is to finish by taking $r$ as it goes to 0 (because as $R$ goes to infinity I proved that the other integral goes to 0)

Comment: I think I got it using the Laurent series

Comment: You can also integrate by part. Noting that there is no singularity at $x=0$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x -1}{x^2}dx=-\int_0^\infty(\cos x-1)d\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=-\frac{\cos x-1}{x}\Big|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that the correct expression you should get is

$$ \int_{r}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x
= \bbox[color:blue;border:1px blue dotted;padding:5px;]{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{S_r} \frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z.$$

The last integral can be computed by noting that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{S_r} \frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z
&= \frac{i}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{e^{rie^{i\theta}}-1}{r e^{i\theta}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \tag{$z = re^{i\theta}$} \\
&\to \frac{i}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} i \, \mathrm{d}\theta \qquad\text{as } r \to 0^+ \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

In general, note that we have the following result (which can be proved in almost the same way as above):

> **Lemma.** Suppose $f$ is meromorphic near $z_0$ and has a *simple pole* at $z_0$. Then, for any $\alpha < \beta$ and with the circular arc $\gamma_r(\theta) = z_0 + re^{i\theta}$, $\alpha \leq \theta \leq \beta$, we have
> $$ \lim_{r \to 0^+} \int_{\gamma_r} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = i(\beta-\alpha) \mathop{\underset{z=z_0}{\mathrm{Res}}} f(z). $$