# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin^3(x)/x^3 dx$ without finding an analytic continuation, still using complex analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, analytic-continuation

There is a similar post regarding the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin^3(x)/x^3 dx$ on Stack. The reason I have some trouble with this post is because it gives an analytic continuation of the function $\sin^3(x)/x^3=\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2iz}\right)^3$, namely $h(z)=-\frac{e^{3iz}-3e^{iz}}{4z^3}-\frac{1}{2z^3}$. Firstly, I'd like to know how such an analytic continuation is obtained. Regarding the sinc function, I know that sine has a zero of order 1, and the denominator also does, so at $z=0$, there is a removable singularity and thus an analytic continuation. I also know that $\lim_{z\to 0}\text{sinc}(z)=1$ (meaning 1 is an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$?)

Regarding the actual integral itself, I have considered the usual indented semicircle, of radius $R$, with an $\epsilon$ semicircle about the essential singularity 0. Without using that analytic continuation $h(z)$, this gives, letting $f(z)=\frac{e^{3iz}-3e^{iz}+3e^{-iz}-e^{-3iz}}{z^3}$
$$0=\frac{i}{8}\left[\int_{[-R,-\epsilon]\cup [\epsilon, R]}  f(z)dz+\oint_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz+\oint_{\gamma_\epsilon}f(z)dz\right]$$
where $\gamma_R$ is the contour of the large semicircle of radius $R$, and $\gamma_\epsilon$ is the contour around the singularity $0$ of radius $\epsilon$. Using Jordan's Lemma, I have managed to show that the integral over $\gamma_R$ goes to 0 as $R\to\infty$. The trouble comes in with the integral over $\gamma_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. I have come across a lemma here on Stack that says if $f$ is some meromorphic function (which, by definiton means that if $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f$ there exists some $r>0$ such that $1/f$ extends to a holomorphic function on $B_r(z_0)$) that has a simple pole at a point $z_0$, then $\lim_{\epsilon\to z_0}\oint_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)d{z} = i(\gamma_\epsilon(b)-\gamma_\epsilon(b))\text{Res}(z_0,f(z))$. This is in fact the reason I asked about the analytic continuation; since the singularity of sinc is essential, this lemma does not apply unless we extend it to some other function that has a pole, at least as I understand it. I also know the answer should be $3\pi/4$.

If anyone could help, I would appreciate it. The link to the post is: [$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3} \, dx$ using contour integration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464730/int-infty-infty-frac-sin3-xx3-dx-using-contour-integration)

Comment: First, the singularity of sinc is not essential, it is $\textit{removable}$, so the indentation lemma you wrote applies to the $\epsilon$ arc. Also, because the function $\frac{e^{3iz}-3e^{iz}+3e^{-iz}-e^{-3iz}}{z^3}$ has exponential terms with negative imaginary argument ($e^{-iz}$ and $e^{-3iz}$) the integral around the large arc will $\textit{not}$ tend to zero as $R\to \infty$. That is the reason the function $h(z)$ you defined first was used in the other solution - it features only exponentials with positive imaginary argument

Comment: Ah, that was an oversight! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a method which doesn't use analytic continuation (or contours). Begin with the known integral
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
Integrating by parts once and then twice gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2} = \left. \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right|_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} (1-\cos x) \frac{-1}{x^2} \, dx &= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \, dx \\
 &= \left. \frac{x-\sin x}{x^2} \right|_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} (x-\sin x) \frac{-2}{x^3} \, dx \\
&= 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} \, dx \end{align*}
so
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
Substituting $3x$ for $x$ gives
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{3x-\sin(3x)}{x^3} \, dx = \frac{9\pi}{4} $$
Now use the identity $\sin(3x) = 3\sin x-4\sin^3x$ to write
$$ \frac{9\pi}{4} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{3x-3\sin x +4\sin^3x}{x^3} \, dx = 3\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} \, dx +4\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3x}{x^3} \, dx $$
and rearrange. This method can be used to compute all of the integrals $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^nx}{x^n} \, dx, \; n \in \mathbb{N}$ recursively.

Comment: This is definitely a clever approach for the general way to evaluate these integrals, so thanks for your response! However, I am a bit more curious with how it *can* be calculated with contours.

Comment: I think any contour approach would need to use the exponential representation of sine. The function you define, $h(z) = \frac{3e^{iz}-e^{3iz}-2}{4z^3}$, has integral around the large arc tending to zero (since there are no $e^{-iz}$ terms), and at zero there is a simple pole, so you can use the indentation lemma you wrote to evaluate the $\epsilon$ arc integral. Also, $h(z) = \frac{3\cos z-\cos(3z)-2}{4z^3} + i \frac{\sin^3z}{z^3}$ by the triple angle formula above, so evaluate the integral then take the imaginary part.

Comment: What has confused me in particular is where that $h(z)$ comes from. I don't know how to actually find that analytic continuation.

Comment: Knowing how to choose the right function comes from experience with these sorts of problems. In this case, we need the exponentials to have positive real part, since we want the integral to tend to zero on an arc in the upper half plane, and we also want the function to contain the integral we wish to calculate as either its real or imaginary part, and in order to make the computation feasible we require the function to have (at most) a pole of order 1 on the contour. Now construct such a function. The simplest one having all three of these properties is $h$.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good application of Laplace techniques for an even function.
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^3\left(x\right)\frac{1}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\left[\sin^3\left(t\right)\right](x)\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2}{s^3}\right](x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac14\left(\frac{3}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{x^2+9}\right)x^2\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{27}{4}\frac{1}{x^2+9}-\frac34\frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac34\pi.
\end{align}

$\mathcal{L}[\sin^3t]=\frac14\mathcal{L}[3\sin(t)-\sin(3t)]$ from trigonometry formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method which just uses IBP, not using analytic continuation (or contours). In fact,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^3\left(x\right)\frac{1}{x^3}\;\mathrm{d}x&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin^3\left(x\right)\frac{1}{x^3}\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^{\infty}\sin^3(x)\;\mathrm{d}(x^{-2})\\
&\overset{IBP}=-3\int_0^{\infty}\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\;\mathrm{d}(x^{-1})\\
&\overset{IBP}=\frac34\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-\sin(x)+3\sin(3x)}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac34(-\frac\pi2+\frac{3\pi}{2})\\
&=\frac34\pi.
\end{align}